# the use of addClass/removeClass of a table td with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, addclass, removeclass

The following code outputs a table with values, and according to the value, it gets a layout. I use jQuery (Ajax) to update the information every 10 seconds.

**php script that generates the wanted variables and stores (echoes) them into a json array (example.php)**

```
$variable1 = 20;

if ($variable1 > 0) {
$td_variable1class="positive";
} else {
$td_variable1class="negative";
}

$array['variable1']      = $variable1;
$array['td_variable1']   = $td_variable1;

echo json_encode($array);
```

**html table where the variable is retrieved from the json generated by the example.php:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='variable1class'>
        <div id='variable1'></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     refresh();
    });

    function refresh() {
         $.getJSON('example.php', function(data) {
            $('div#variable1').html(data.variable1);
            $('td.td_variable1').addClass(data.td_variable1);
       });
    setTimeout("refresh()",10000);
   }
```

The problem is the "addClass" **adds** a class to the existing class, resulting in an output like this:

before the refresh:

```
<td class="td_variable1 positive">
```

after (assuming the variable changed from positive to negative):

```
<td class="td_variable1 positive negative">
```

I tried to avoid this by using removeclass:

```
$('td.td_variable1').removeClass().addClass(data.td_variable1);
```

But then the actual class name of the td is removed and my output looks like this:

```
<td class="negative">
```

and it should look like this:

```
<td class="td_variable1 negative">
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The comments below are confusing. Can you simply save out a sample page from the browser so we can see the generated code and HTML (not just the source)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only have those 2 options, remove both (and only those two) then add the new one:

```
$('td.td_variable1').removeClass("positive negative").addClass(data.td_variable1);
```

Comment: the classes itself are also variable, so I can't add all those classes. I tried this: $('td.td_variable1').removeClass(data.td_variable1).addClass(data.td_variable1); but that does nothing, it keeps adding.

Comment: @Roddeh: The aim is not clear... how will you differentiate between the classes you want to keep untouched and the ones that get modified? (e.g. retain `td_variable1`)

Comment: I just want to update them, and remove the existing class. the problem is that it keeps adding classes, and I want them to be removed first, and then replaced.

Comment: @Roddeh: The code is not clear on how you manage the names. Do you have a array/collection of all the possible class names anywhere?

Comment: I'm affraid I will have to remove them manually as you suggested. Yes, it's a long list of classes. It would have been easier if the first part could stay in place while only the last part would be deleted, but I guess thats not possible :). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Roddeh: You can iterate the collection class names and possible match on some pattern of which to retain/remove, but I would need to see more examples before I could suggest any code for that.

Comment: I don't really have a pattern :) but hey, my problem is solved. Probably not the most efficient method and a bit dirty, but that's ok :) thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

[`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) removes all classes when not given any parameter. Use `.removeClass("negative")` instead.